# Search a User and View Repositories with Github API in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, github-api

I'm trying to make an app with Rails that allows you to search for a user and it displays their repositories and I can't seem to work out how to render to the page.

I've created a Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    @repos = []
    users.each do |user|
      url = 'https://api.github/users/'
      response = HTTParty.get(url + username + '/repos')

      @repos << response.parsed_response
    end
  end
end
```

But not sure how to get an input and allocate it to the username parameter and then render to the page.

I would then ideally like to also display properties from the repos as well but i'm assuming I can just add '/example' to the response.

Just getting to grips with Ruby so help would be greatly appreciated!